# Magento Admin Email inline css fallback

Tags: magento-1.9, email

We have implemented our own `email-inline.css` file within our theme folder - `skin/frontend/package/theme/css/email-inline.css`.  This works great for emails that are triggered by frontend actions that include `{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}` - such as new order email `locale/en_GB/template/email/sales/order_new.html`.

However, it seems to cause an issue with certain templates, and fallback to the base email-inline.css file - such as `locale/en_GB/template/email/outofstock_subscription.html`.

My hunch is that these are templates when the email is triggered by the admin system (or at least not the frontend).

Is there a way to test this, and is there a way to explictly ensure that the correct `area` is loaded when an email is sent?

Comment: Without knowing how your implementation is done, you could possibly try: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29148/what-is-the-effect-of-magegetstore-setidmage-core-model-appadmin-store-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a missing call to `->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>$storeId))` on the `core/email_template` model in a 3rd party extension.